# Automatically Populate list on webpage startup - React, Redux, Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I'm creating a webpage which has two components, one , **Categories** and two, **Items**

With the help of a function *initCategories()* i am calling inside the *componentDidMount()* of Categories, I am able to display all the categories on my screen. The *initCategories()* function calls the action which is responsible to fetch all categories from Firestore

I want to show all the items inside the **Items** table that have the category field with the ID of first category in **Categories** table on startup. I get the *firstCategoryId* as props with *mapStateToProps* method. I was trying to call an action in **action.js** file and pass this id in my *componentDidMount()* method inside the **items** in order to fetch all items.

How can I tackle this?

**Update**

Categories Table contain categoryName and categoryId.
Items table contains itemId, itemName and category. The category field in Item table saves the ID of the category that the item belongs to

**mapStateToProps()**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("mapping called")
    return {
      items: state.itemReducer.itemsOnDisplay,
      currentCategoryId: state.reducer.currentCategoryId
    };
  }
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
    //   onCategoryAdded: (category) => dispatch(actionCreators.addCategory(category)),
    //   onCategoryDeleted: (categoryId) => dispatch(actionCreators.deleteCategory(categoryId)),
      loadItemsInCategory: (categoryId) => dispatch(itemActionCreators.loadItemsInCategory(categoryId)),
    }
  }
```

**componentDidMount()**

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.loadItemsInCategory(this.props.currentCategoryId)
}
```

Comment: `ComponentDidMount gets called before the mapStateToProps() gets called`. That is not true, I don't know why you get that impression

Comment: Yeah You are right. I checked again. I'll remove that line from the post

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem. In `mapStateToProps` you pass `firstCategoryId` to the component. Inside the `componentDidMount` you call `initCategories()` using the `firstCategoryId` from the props

Comment: yes. and the firstCategoryId that I pass to the initCategories method turns out to be undefined. Thats the problem

Comment: Show us your mapStateToProps and your componentDidMount please

Comment: updated with the post with the functions

Comment: I think you are not accessing the state properties in the correct way. `state.reducer.currentCategoryId` is undefined at startup, you need to init that value in the store before mounting react itself

Comment: Thank you @gbalduzzi . I could figure it out with your help. I'm answering the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Thank you all, especially @gbalduzzi for helping me solve it.

**The actual problem as I understand:** When the store gets created, the reducer is initialized with the default values. That's when the componentDidMount() gets called for the first time. When the values from firebase are downloaded, components gets updated. This time, it is the *componentDidUpdate()* method which gets fired.

```
componentDidUpdate()
```

**Solution:**

I added the following code. With this, I'm loading items only when the components get updated with the values from the firebase.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if(this.props.currentCategoryId!== prevProps.currentCategoryId){
    this.props.loadItemsInCategory(this.props.currentCategoryId)
  }
}
```

Comment: @gbalduzzi hope I haven't made errors in the answer

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you using hooks?

With a stateless component using hooks you could do something like:

```
// items.jsx
const { categoryId } = props;
const [items, setItems] useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchItemsByCategoryId(categoryId).then(items => setItems(items));
}, [categoryId])

return <ul>{items.map((item) = <li><Item item={item} /></li>)</ul>
```

I suggest you read the docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: I am not using hooks. I use classes

Comment: What is the difference with using componentDidMount in OP case? Outside of stlystic preference